# Collection view cell contents autolayout

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

How to automatically manage collection view cell contents by autolayout constraints.
I have used collectinview delegate method sizeForItem() method, but that couldn't serve the purpose.

Comment: It would be nice if you could put some code from your flow layout, or at least from your delegate if you're using the default flow layout.

Comment: Please check this link, may help you - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48948098/set-uicollectionviewcell-width-programmatically-to-uicollectionview-width/48961656#48961656

Answer (score 0):

You will have to apply autolayout constraints to views inside the class definition of your UICollectionViewCell, or consider using UIStackViews inside it

Comment: Don't want to apply stackView OR I have applied correctly autolayout constraints in collectionViewCell in IB, not programmatically. But Want something like that is achievable in tableview with 2/3 lines of code e.g - Estimated height, automaticRowHeight dimension.